# send parameter to controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I building a eshop site looks like this: 
[image]

I load all the products and when I hover over the product name I see dynamic url made by the id of the product

[image]

So far so good, the problem is that I've hard-coded the product details page.

What I want to know is how can I send a parameter to a controller so I can load the page based on the product id:

```
app.factory("shopFactory", function ($resource) {
    return {
        User: $resource("http://localhost:58495/users/api/User/?id=:id", { id: "@id" }),
        Category: $resource("http://localhost:58495/category/api/categories"),
        Product: $resource("http://localhost:58495/products/api/Products?from=:from&to=:to", { from: "@from", to: "@to" }),
        ProductDetail: $resource("http://localhost:58495/products/api/Products?id=:id", { id: "@id" }),
        Test: $resource("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/:id", {id:"@id"})
    };

});
```

my factory look like that, my product Controller:

```
app.controller("productCtrl", function ($scope, shopFactory) {
    var test = shopFactory.ProductDetail.get({ id: 1 }).$promise.then(function (response) {
      CODE HERE
    }); 
});
```

I do not how but I want to send to the controller a parameter which is the id of the product I wanna see, the controller receives that id as a argument and insert it here :

```
var test = shopFactory.ProductDetail.get({ id: **hardCoded Part** }).$promise.then(function (response) {
      CODE HERE
    });
```

Then I load all the info based of the argument I received.
Any idea how to do it? This approach is the right one? Or how can I do it? 
Thanks

Comment: where is your HTML?  Is that where the IDs are hardcoded?

Comment: @RaniRadcliff the hardcoded part is the id, I put 1 as the productId

Comment: How much of it works currently? When you click the hyperlink, the view changes out and shows the correct things?

Comment: @CameronRodriguez All the data I retrieve works and gets displayed in the HTML just as the second image, but I have to manually change the id, for example 2, 3 ,99, when I change the id number, all the data from that product displays properly, what I don't know is how to dynamic load the number of the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , Dunno how but what I was looking for was : $routeProvider, I fixed my problem with

```
var test = shopFactory.ProductDetail.get({ id: $routeParams.producId }).$promise.then(function (response) {
    CODE HERE
 });
```

Basically I get the id parameter from the url , and load insert it into the id, which was what I wanted, a very good article explaining it: https://namitamalik.github.io/routeParams-in-AngularJS/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
<a ng-click="productCtrl.showDetails(product.id)>{{product.name}}</a>
```

Then in the controller

```
$scope.showDetails = function(productId) {
    shopFactory.ProductDetail.get({ id: productId }).$promise.then(function 
      (response) {
        CODE HERE
    }); 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found another way, which I think is the right way, if I haven't found it I would use yours.